# What is the name of this software design behavior?

Tags: performance, software-design

When a software has a set of functionality where some of the functionality is provided with multiple implementations and the software automatically decides which one to use. So for instance:

An image editor that has image effects and some its effects like Blur, Median, etc is provided with both CPU and GPU implementations but not directly exposed to the user as options but rather the software decides which one to use based on the user's hardware.

Or in another case where the software chooses which sorting algorithm to use based on the data it has on the items to sort.

I guess this only happens in performance related features.

But what's the name of this feature/idea when a software has this workflow?

Is it called `transparent execution`? Or `context sensitive`? I seem to recall a term used to describe this behavior.

EDIT: Btw I am also interested in hearing the marketing term for this? Like `ProgramX` supports `transparent execution`.

Comment: It's called "off topic on SO". :-)

Comment: This is not OT. Asking for a name of the design pattern.

Comment: It'd fit a lot better on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

This is [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

You pass the same object to multiple implementations where the difference is the algorithm. This is a **classic** case of **[strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.**

Comment: Btw I am also interested in hearing the marketing term for this? Like ProgramX supports "transparent execution".

Comment: +1 Thought it sounded like a facade, but a quick check of the GOF book confirms that strategy is a better fit.

Comment: @Joan Happy to help. Someone gave downvote did not leave a comment.

Comment: Yes I noticed, but don't worry the downvoter isn't me :O

Comment: @Joan Yeah I know. Downvote itself is nothing, but not leaving a comment is against SO code of conduct :)

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately some people are like that :O

Comment: @Aliostad, @Joan Venge - Actually, I don't believe it's necessarily against any sort of "code of conduct." There are some good points against it, actually, on [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment). I think it's up to the downvoter's discretion whether or not to leave a comment. *tl;dr* - Sometimes leaving a comment leads to (undue, of course) reciprocity against the downvoter.

Comment: Yes, and also it is down to customer's discretion to tip or not and how much but giving 10% tip is considered a normal practice and is normally expected from people.

Comment: @Aliostad - Oh, for sure. I appreciate knowing why people downvote me, so I prefer to leave comments if I do it myself. I'm just saying that it's still up in the air whether or not it should be "required" by the community.

Comment: Btw guys do you know the marketing name for this? Should I ask this on programmers SO? Like how would you advertise it?

Comment: There is a similar pattern called `Visitor` which might be more marketing friendly! But to be honest apart from strategy or policy pattern, I have not heard any other name.

Comment: Marketing name?  The *strategy pattern* is in the Design Patterns book (page 315) - that's its given name.

Comment: *Visitor* lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates.  I've got the book open now!

Comment: Yeah I need to communicate this to the average non-programmer users that will recognize what I mean. But strategy pattern would definitely not be understood by them, especially if it requires further reading to see what it is :O

Comment: Also in case it's not clear I mean advertising this to my customers who are artists.

Comment: `communicate this to the average non-programmer` Good luck! :)

Comment: But there is a user friendly term for this no? Otherwise how will people know the app is using say GPU effects when you have the hardware for it, instead of effects that appear just standard CPU heavy slow versions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the facade design pattern, from the GOF book page 185:

> Provide a unified interface to a set
>   of interfaces in a subsystem.  Facade
>   defines a higher level interface that
>   makes the subsystem easier to use.

Comment: Strategy sounds like a better fit.